# Collation Conflict in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Currently using SQL Server 2014 and having an issue with the Collation on a stored procedure.  I currently have a report that runs a stored procedure, the code works fine when run in SSMS but I have noticed that while it is being run as part of a SSRS report there is a collation issue between `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` and `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

My database is set at `Latin1_General_CI_AS` as well as all my table columns so I am at a loss as to where it is pulling this `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` inconsistency, can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS` is the default collation for SSRS.

Either you write your SQL queries with the `COLLATE` property on all your string comparisons or reinstall SSRS with the correct default collation.

Keep in mind that if you use `ALTER DATABASE` to change the SSRS database collation, it won't affect already created objects, just new ones from that point onwards.

---

If this is a problem with a particular column (and not the whole database), you can run this query to check all column's current collation.

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name),
    Collation = c.collation_name
FROM 
    sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    C.collation_name is not null
ORDER BY 
    1
```

Then use `ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> <type> COLLATE <newCollate>` to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ezlo, my report database is already set to Latin1_General_CI_AS so I am thinking this is something table specific as I have many reports running without this issue.

Comment: @PJD I've added a query you can use to check current collations. Try to find the one that's breaking your report.